# I modify response.data in Django REST Framework view.py. Why am I getting an AttributeError during testing but not with actual API use?

Tags: python, django, rest, unit-testing, frameworks

My Django REST Framework API is working just as expected. In view.py, I modify OrderViewSet, def partial_update, to add another key/value pair to the response.data dict before it is saved to the db. It works without errors when I call the API with Postman.

However, when I run tests for the same functionality it fails and returns:

```
request.data["submission_date"] = datetime.now()
AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable
```

Why would I get this error during testing if it is not occurring during actual API use?

View.py

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ Includes custom PATCH functionality """
    queryset = Order.objects.all().order_by('-order_date')
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Update status and timestamp fields accordingly """
        status = request.data['status']

        if status == 'submitted':
            request.data["submission_date"] = datetime.now()

        if status == 'packaged':
            request.data["packaged_date"] = datetime.now()

        if status in ['sold', 'canceled', 'abandoned']:
            request.data["finished_date"] = datetime.now()

        return super().partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Test.py

```
def test_patch_order_status_from_cart_to_submitted(self):
    """ test patching order status from cart to submitted """
    order = sample_order(user=self.user)

    payload = {
        "status": "submitted"
    }

    res = self.client.patch(order_detail_url(order.id), payload)
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    patched_order = Order.objects.get(id=order.id)
    self.assertEqual(patched_order.status, 'submitted')

def test_submitted_timestamp(self):
    """ test that patching order status to submitted also leaves timestamp """
    order = sample_order(user=self.user)

    payload = {
        "status": "submitted"
    }

    self.client.patch(order_detail_url(order.id), payload)

    patched_order = Order.objects.get(id=order.id)
    self.assertNotEqual(patched_order.submission_date, None)
```

Edit:

If I were to modify a copy of request.data as below, how could I then return it from the function?

```
    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Update status and timestamp accordingly """
    modified_data = request.data.copy()
    status = request.data['status']

    if status == 'submitted':
        modified_data["submission_date"] = datetime.now()

    if status == 'packaged':
        modified_data["packaged_date"] = datetime.now()

    if status in ['sold', 'canceled', 'abandoned']:
        modified_data["finished_date"] = datetime.now()

    return super().partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

### Solution: Now the tests pass.

views.py:

```
    ...

    def partial_update(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Update status and timestamp accordingly """
        order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = OrderSerializer(order, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Serializers.py:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def update(self, order, validated_data):
        """ Update status and timestamp accordingly """
        status = validated_data.get('status')
        order.status = status
        if status == 'submitted':
            order.submission_date = datetime.now()
        elif status == 'packaged':
            order.packaged_date = datetime.now()
        elif status in ['sold', 'canceled', 'abandoned']:
            order.finished_date = datetime.now()

        order.save()
        return order

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'user')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean modifying request.data? I also got this error before.

Then I read [Django documentation QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), I think the "request.data":

- is dictionary-like, not dictionary.
- data type is immutable.
- copy that before modifying, like:

  ```
   req_data = request.data.copy()
   req_data['submission_date'] = datetime.now()
  ```

And the reason of error not occurring during actual API use, maybe just the status not in these conditions.

On the other hand, in this case I usually set a modified_at or created_at [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) in models.py, so that will record the submission_date automatically whenever the data is modified or created. I feel that is convenient.

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text="submission_date")
modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, help_text="re-submission_date")
```

**Edit** for another possible solution by using ModelSerializer:

Purpose: We want to update the data not just based on request.data directly.
We want to use some other logic:  if status == 'submitted' then...

And I suppose submission_date, packaged_date, finished_date are fields of Order Model.

views.py

```
def partial_update(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = OrderSerializer(order, data=request.data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

serializers.py

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, order, validated_data):
        status = validated_data.get('status')
        order.status = status
        if status == 'submitted':
            order.submission_date = datetime.now()
        elif status == 'packaged':
            order.packaged_date = datetime.now()
        elif status in ['sold', 'canceled', 'abandoned']:
            order.finished_date = datetime.now()

        order.save()
        return order
```

Comment: created_at and modified_at don't work in this case. created_at occurs before submission_date and is irrelevant. modified_at is overwritten when any Model field is updated, and I need it to only be updated once for the specific change to the status field. As for making a copy of request.data, I need to return the request object including the new values at the end of the function (the updates are not made as side-effects in the function). I can't return a modified copy of the entire request object because, AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'copy'.

Comment: Yes, the 'Request' object has no attribute 'copy', you copy the request right?
Could you try: request.data.copy()? not request.copy()
That's worked in my project in django 4.0

Comment: If I were to modify a copy of request.data, how could I then return it from the function? (see edit in main post).

Comment: Yeah, you are right, there is a problem to put the data back to the function. How about use the ModelSerializer() to solve the case instead? I will try to edit the answer.

Comment: That solved it, the logic belonged in serializers.py and not view.py. Your files were almost perfect, except for two changes: 1) In serializers.py, def update needs the line "order.status = status" or order.status wont update; 2) In views.py, the serializer needs to include partial=True so that the patch request only needs to include value to change. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm so glad to see the case was solved, thank you ~